# confirmations: 0 vs confirmations: -1?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, confirmations, zero-confirmation, chain-reorganization

I'm looking at a bitcoin clone, not sure what codebase it was cloned from, but I've noticed that the listSinceBlock output sometimes includes:

- a receive that has 0 confirmations
- a send that has 0 confirmations
- a send that has -1 confirmations

What is the significance of these counts? Does 0 mean that the transaction was never mined (too low fee?) versus the -1 meaning that that transaction has only ever been seen in a now-stale block? (chain reorg, new best chain doesn't include the block that held these transactions)

These transactions are fairly old (months) so if something was going to happen with them by now, i think it would have..